# dynamic variable combining a double value + filter

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-filter

I have the following case:

`<bl-card :subtitle="card.beforeChanged + ' ' + (card.changed | formatDate)" />`

The subtitle needs to be set by combining two strings. `card.beforeChanged` contains *"last changed to:"* string, the `card.changed` variable contains a datetimestring. Via de `formatDate()` the datetimestring gets formatted to a readable date.

subtitle now returns: "last changed to: 2069882880".

The question: is it possible to combine two strings where one of them get's formatted via the filter property in one go?

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working through a method. Computed properties weren't an option since the datestring comes from within a for loop in the template.

Method:

```
formatDate: (date, format) => {
  if (!date) return ''
  if (!format) format = 'DD.MM.YYYY'
  return moment(date).format(format)
}
```

Implementation:

```
<bl-column v-for="(card, index) in cards" :key="card.id">
     <bl-card :index="index" type="section" action="drawer" :title="card.titleShort" :subtitle="(card.beforeChanged || '') + ' ' + formatDate(card.changed)" />
</bl-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [computer property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) for that.

```js
Vue.filter('formatDate', function (value) {
    return moment(value).fromNow()
})

Vue.component('todo', {
        computed: {
        formatedText: function () {
        return `${this.text} - ${Vue.filter('formatDate')(this.date)}`
        }
    },
        props: ['text', 'date'],
    template: '<li>{{ formatedText }}</li>'
});

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
      todos: [
        {text:'testing', date: new Date()},
        {text:'old text', date: moment().subtract(7, 'days')}
      ]
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo" v-cloak>
    <p v-if="!todos.length">No todos at this moment.</p>
    <ul v-else>
        <todo v-for="t in todos" :text=t.text :date=t.date></todo>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't work since the date came from a variable within a for loop in the template. Since computed properties don't accept variables this didn't work.